# Perl : Couldn’t use Text::Wrap:wrap() as per exact requirement

Tags: string, perl

I would like to restrict the column number to 45 characters. I am using the `Text::Wrap:wrap` as below.

```
$Text::Wrap::columns = 44;
print FOUT wrap('','' ,<FIN>);
```

It is making all the colums to 44 chars without word breakage. But it is reducing spaces for some of the lines at the begining.

**Text before using `wrap()`:**

```
EVENTS: KINJHK QDFMED QDFMED
        QDFMED KINJHK QDFMED
        KINJHK

BUTIONS: 52314 KINJHK KINJHKQDFMED
         QDFMED42 KINJHK524 MBCXZ
         56.321 ILOLKI 421
```

**TeXt after using `wrap()`**

```
EVENTS: KINJHK QDFMED QDFMED
      QDFMED KINJHK QDFMED
      KINJHK

BUTIONS: 52314 KINJHK KINJHKQDFMED
      QDFMED42 KINJHK524 MBCXZ
      56.321 ILOLKI 421
```

For example in the `EVENTS` section the spaces are reduced before the line `QDFMED KINJHK QDFMED` and the below lines. But I want the alignment should not be disturbed after using `wrap()` method.

I have tried many ways of using this wrap, but no use. Could any please help me.

Thanks.
Vis.

Comment: Is it possible that some of the whitespace is actual tab stops? Could be an issue with the tab width. Just guessing ...

Answer (score 2):

Which version of the Text::Wrap module are you using? Using 2009.0305 as in

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::Wrap;

# demo only
*FIN = *DATA;
*FOUT = *STDOUT;

$Text::Wrap::columns = 44;
print FOUT wrap('', '', <FIN>);

__DATA__
EVENTS: KINJHK QDFMED QDFMED
        QDFMED KINJHK QDFMED
        KINJHK

BUTIONS: 52314 KINJHK KINJHKQDFMED
         QDFMED42 KINJHK524 MBCXZ
         56.321 ILOLKI 421
```

produces the output you want and does not reduce the indentation.

```
EVENTS: KINJHK QDFMED QDFMED
        QDFMED KINJHK QDFMED
        KINJHK

BUTIONS: 52314 KINJHK KINJHKQDFMED
         QDFMED42 KINJHK524 MBCXZ
         56.321 ILOLKI 421
```

Note: all whitespace in the code is space characters, no TABs. Replacing spaces with leading TAB characters made no difference in the output, however.

Perhaps there is some other important bit of context in your code that we don’t yet know about.